# Google Tag Manager - Some Click URL shows undefined

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have setup two user-defined variables in GTM:
[image]

The 2nd one is the same. I just ask for another QueryKey. Here is my Trigger:
[image]

And here my tag:
[image]

The click url always looks the same. Example:
https://example.com/test?productCodes=999.999.999&culture=de-CH

The problem is, that I often get **undefined** as Event Action and **(not set)** as Event Label in Google Analytics:

[image]
[image]

Is there any idea why?

Thanks for supporting me.

Bests,
Yab86

Comment: Are your sure that all click links are present and contain parameters?

Comment: Good question. Will check that! Thanks zborovskaya

Comment: Hi hborovskaya. Yes, the click url always contains the parameters and are present

Comment: May be to check for mobile devices?

Comment: For an accurate result you can try another filter in trigger: Click URL instead of CSS Selector and use RegExp.

Comment: On google analytics add as secondary dimensión the page and you ll most probably fount people without this parameters.